# Emacs C-h c doesn't seem to work for chords 3 combinations long?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to use `C-h c` in emacs to figure out what a key combination is bound to. The combination is `C-u C-c C-q`, which realigns tags in org-mode. However, Emacs just tries to look up `C-u C-c` and then fails. What am I doing wrong? I realize I could easily look at the orgmode source or something to figure this out, but for future reference what would I do to figure out what function something like this is bound to?

Edit: OK, so it's actually `C-u` followed by `C-c C-q`, and according to emacs this is what that combination is bound to:

> (org-set-tags-command &optional arg just-align)
>
> Call the set-tags command for the current entry.

So what exactly does it mean to give this command the argument 4?

Oh, just to give an explanation: I'm trying to start learning emacs-lisp and customization and one of the things I wanted to do was to have this command added to the before-save-hook so that when I save an org file, the tags get automatically aligned.

Final edit: I figured out why this command behaves as it does; given the prefix argument it changes its behavior. How can I set the prefix argument when calling the function in elisp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a general problem with combinations that are three keys long: For example, C-h c ESC ESC ESC (keyboard-escape-quit) or C-h c C-x r t (string-rectangle) both work fine.

When I try C-h c C-u C-c C-q in org-mode, the command interrupts after C-u and shows:

```
C-u runs the command universal-argument
```

in the minibuffer, which is correct. So, in fact, "C-u C-c C-q" is not a command, it's the command "C-c C-q" (org-table-wrap-region) started with an additional argument (4 -- see C-h k C-u for an explanation).

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but this is very confusing to me. I got this command from the orgmode reference card, and it is described as "Realign tags in all headings" and the binding for `C-c C-q` is 

`(org-defkey org-mode-map "\C-c\C-q" 'org-set-tags-command)`

although I'm guessing you just made a typo when you said `org-table-wrap-region`.

Comment: Oh, I guess its' more of this:

>For some commands, just C-u by itself serves as a flag
>which is different in effect from any particular numeric argument.

Hmm... I guess I'll dive into the source then.

Comment: Well, here it says: <code>C-c C-q runs the command org-table-wrap-region</code>; maybe I'm just running a different version of org-mode (6.05) here. I'm not really familiar with org-mode, so I guess I cannot explain this...

Comment: Oh, maybe it's just because it's a different version. Thanks for your help anyway, you basically told me enough to almost do what I wanted. I just need to figure out how to call a function with a prefix argument in elisp.

Comment: Try passing it as a "normal" argument: (org-set-tags-command 4) should do the trick.